# React router & redux update state, change url but not render the route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

**Final update. Everything works as it should now!**

github: https://tornado1979.github.io/movies-socket
1. Update react-router-redux -> "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9"
2. changed the way i dispatch push(location) like so:
`const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
  changeRoute: location => push(location),
}, dispatch)`

**2nd update:**
1. Looks like react-router-redux: 4.0.8 has issues on ReactDom.render...
2. Updated to "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9" and no more :

```
ReactDOM.render(... error
```

3. now the routing updates state + url + component:
 (a). e.g. `<Link to="/movies-socket/1111">2nd more info</Link>` works!
 (b). e.g. `changeRoute: location => dispatch(push(location)),` works at first but gives error on `react-router-redux/es/middleware.js`.
 `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`:

[image]

*I dispatch the action like that:*

```
`const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
     alterViewMode: changeViewMode,
     searchMovies: searchMoviesRequest,
     changeRoute: location => dispatch(push(location)),
 }, dispatch)`
```

**1st update:**
I have it live here on github: https://tornado1979.github.io/movies-socket/  .

1. search a movie
2. click either on the movie button or on the link (the url changes, local i get error on button no error on Link though).
3. when i click on 'Button':
   [image]
4. the click gives that error:
   [image]
   I strive to update the state on route change, so far i have managed only to update the state, the url denies to update.
   On most of the tutorials that i ve found, they use to create the store on the same file with the ReactDOM.render(....), but i have them separate, i create the store and import it on index.js.

### store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { routerMiddleware, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import saga from './sagas'

import { moviesReducer as movies } from './modules/home/reducers/movies'
import { reducer as display } from './components/viewMode/reducers/viewMode'
import { history } from './helpers/history'

const routingMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history)
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

const enhancers = []
const middleware = [
  routingMiddleware,
  sagaMiddleware,
  thunk,
]
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const devToolsExtension = window.devToolsExtension 

if (typeof devToolsExtension === 'function') {
  enhancers.push(devToolsExtension())
 }
 }

const composedEnhancers = compose(
 applyMiddleware(...middleware),
 ...enhancers,
)

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
   display,
   movies,
   routing: routerReducer,
  }),
  composedEnhancers,
 )

  // start sagaMiddleware
  sagaMiddleware.run(saga)

  export default store
```

### index.js ##

*I tried either Router or ConnectedRouter or Router from react-router with no luck.*

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'

// 1. updates state , does not change url, error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undef
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'

// 2. Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) 
   ... index.js
// import { ConnectedRouter as Router, syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react- 
   router-redux'

// 3. updates state , does not change url, error : TypeError: Cannot read 
   property 'type' of undef
// import { Router } from 'react-router'
import { history as browserHistory } from './helpers/history'

import store from './store'

import './index.css'
import App from './App'

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
   <Router history={history}>
     <App />
   </Router>
 </Provider>,
 document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

### app.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import './App.scss'

import { Routes } from './components/routes'
import { Footer } from './components/footer'
import { Header } from './components/header'

const App = () =>
(
<div className="App">
  <Fragment>
    <Header />
    <Routes />
    <Footer bgTemplate="template1" />
  </Fragment>
</div>)

export default App
```

### history.js

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

export const history = createHistory()

history.listen((location, action) => {
  console.log(`The current URL is 
  ${location.pathname}${location.search}${location.hash}`)
    console.log(`The last navigation action was ${action}`)
  })
```

And inside **home.js**, i dispatch the **push('/')** action, that updates state but does not load the '**moviedetails**' component nor the **url**:

i show some snippets of 'home.js'

```
 /*dispatch the push action to change route*/
 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({  
  alterViewMode: changeViewMode,  
  searchMovies: searchMoviesRequest,   
  changeRoute: location => dispatch(push(location)),/* should go to 
  ':/movieId' */  
 }, dispatch)  


  /* Click the button or Link to redirect user to movie details*/
  /* this updates the state on both cases but not the url*/
  <div>
 <p className="panel-text">{movie.overview}</p>
    <button className="view-more" onClick={() => 
       this.props.changeRoute('/11111')}>1st more info </button>
          <Link to="/1111">2nd more info</Link>
        </div>
```

What could i missing here and i cant make it work? thanks.

Comment: I couldn't examine all your code but have you seen this: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4924 Once, I struggled with same problem and solved it with `withRouter`

Comment: thanks i ll take a look.